# When does jquery.trigger fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have gone through the .trigger() document http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ . But still not sure how this fiddle works. The link: https://jsfiddle.net/LanceShi/s7pm43f3/2/

**HTML:**

```
<input id="theInput"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#theInput").trigger("input");
});


$("#theInput").on("input", function() {
    alert("Here");
});
```

Now the input event is fired on every keyup/paste event. But I don't see anywhere in the .trigger() document mentioning this. How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not trigger doing that. Your trigger is only being fired once.

The reason is that `input` event encompasses numerous other events such as keyup, change, paste and a few others also

As noted by others you need to correct your order of calling trigger before adding listener

Answer (score 2):

You need to `register` the event before you can `invoke`. Since you have declare a DOM event ( something which is not registered as a jquery event ) , you need to use the function `trigger()`. For the ones which are pre-defined in jquery ( like `click`, `change` ) , you can invoke them directly without the need of `trigger`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#theInput").on("input", function() {
    alert("Here");
  });

    $("#theInput").trigger("input");
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/s7pm43f3/3/

Comment: that's what i meant. i was just trying to pull out the difference.

Comment: custom events are completely different. Like bootstrap for example will use things like `$().on('bs.modal.show')`. Triggering an event is not the same thing and `input` is a native event in html5

Comment: corrected the verbiage. thanks for the intervention.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `.trigger()` have no any effect because your `trigger()` will fire before `input` event attached.

So your code should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#theInput").on("input", function() {
    alert("Here");
  }).trigger('input');
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7pm43f3/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here the explanation

As you have read in the documentation of jQuery, the Trigger function execute a custom event, well see here is executed

```
$("#theInput").trigger("input");
```

And where the hanlder is added was here

```
$("#theInput").on("input", function() {
    alert("Here");
});
```

include what you say, when you write something in the input element runs what is in the function

```
function() {
    alert("Here");
}
```

This is confusing at first because at first glance do not know what happens.
By adding the handler to #theInput you are adding a listener to the event type "input"
In JavaScript there is an event of type "input"
It works for elements "input" and "textarea" and this is executed when its value is changed or in other words when we write about them.
So really what this code is doing that.
Add a listener to #theInput with an event type "input".
If you want more information you can read the following:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input